# Jquery fadeId fadeOut below lower z-indexed div

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm laying the ground work for creating a menu bar that fades the background when hovered. The background will be the whole page using a png graphic that is semi transparent and positioned over the whole page.

I have the jquery doing it's job but it seems to ignore the z-index of the menu div which I'm trying not to have "under" the transparent png div layer.

To recap - Page loads and there is a div with a transparent png fully covering working area (#overlay).
The #overlay div also is set to have display:none; so it initially does not show.
When there is a hover over the menu div, the overlay div fadesIn covering the work area. 
The menu div is set to z-index:20 and the overlay div z-index is at 10
The problem is that the overlay div covered the menu and seems to not respect the z-index layer value.

Can someone please help me understand how to achieve this goal without having to resize the overlay to exclude the menu area (margin-top = menu height).

http://jsfiddle.net/ERepZ/

```
$("#box").hover(function () {
    $(this).children("#overlay").fadeIn();
    }, function () {
$(this).children("#overlay").stop().fadeOut();
});
```

UPDATE:
This code will isolate the menu area which is more inline with a menu hover action:

```
var animationSpeed = 400;
var fadeMax = 0.5;
var fadeMin = 0;
$("#menu").hover(function() {
$("#overlay").stop().fadeTo(animationSpeed, fadeMax);
    }, function() {
$("#overlay").stop().fadeTo(animationSpeed, fadeMin);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMmSb/1/

(built on Ruben Infante's code below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only items that are positioned (e.g., `position: relative`, `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`) can utilize z-index.

```
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    height:50px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color:#999;
    z-index:20;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bBv5R/)

**Suggestion:**

If you would like to get away from using an image to span your entire web page, you can also simply use a solid background color and vary the opacity during your animation using [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

CSS

```
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: #000;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

JS

```
var animationSpeed = 400;
var fadeMax = 0.5;
var fadeMin = 0;
$("#box").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("#overlay").stop().fadeTo(animationSpeed, fadeMax);
}, function() {
    $(this).children("#overlay").stop().fadeTo(animationSpeed, fadeMin);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sMmSb/)

Comment: Z-index also applies to `position:fixed`

Comment: @Dom Thanks for catching that omission. I forgot to include that one.